# Class attribute manipulation outside of main() in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm really new to Dart and the tutorials and classes that I've been watching doesn't cover this really basic problem that I'm having.

```
class Animals {
    Cat myCat = Cat();
    myCat.name = 'dexter';
}

class Cat {
    String? name;
}
```

When I try to instantiate and manipulate a class outside of main() I get the following error:

```
Error: A method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
   myCat.name = 'dexter';
```

Coding in Swift Playground I could do something like this:

```
var myPet = Animals();
myPet.myCat.name = "dexter"
print(myPet.myCat.name);

class Animals {
    var myCat = Cat();
}

class Cat {
    var name: String = "";
}
```

Comment: _"Class manipulation..."_ - I didn't know Karl Marx had opinions on OOP

Comment: You can’t write code in a class, you need to define a method and do it there, or add it as a constructor argument and give it there.